# AT+CMGS returns ERROR 302

Tags: command, sms, at-command

I'm trying to send a SMS using AT commands and after typing the cellphone number it show the CMS: ERROR 302.

What I'm doing:

```
AT

OK

AT+CMGF=1

OK

AT+CMGS="<3 digit local area code><7 digit cellphone number>"<Enter>

+CMS: ERROR 302
```

I've found this post: [AT+CMGS returns ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522794/atcmgs-returns-error) but couldn't find a solution. Am I typing something wrong? I've changed SMS-encoding to GMS as the post describes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AT

AT+CMGF=1

AT+CSCA="sms tel. service",145

AT+CMGS="tel. number"
text message here
^Z
```

Some modems need set CSCA (SMS Service Center Address) always.

And look [here](http://www.developershome.com/sms/cmgsCommand3.asp) for a examples and descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that sending exactly the same AT commands by hand worked, but sending them from a controller did not (with waiting for the correct answers). Getting the 302 error. But then doing all commands a lot slower with waits of 2 secs in between it suddenly started to work. Apparantly the SIM900 needs more time after it answers, or something.